# Getting a custom SBC board developed to spec

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino

I need to design a single-board computer to the following specs. Can anyone please suggest companies that could build this economically?

- Two full-size (USB-A) USB 3 ports
- A CPU fast enough to handle full-speed transfer to/from both ports simultaneously
- A few available GPIO pins
- A battery, charging circuitry, a micro-USB port or USB-C port for charging
- The system can run "barebones", i.e. doesn't need to run Linux

Comment: What are your requirements in terms of CPU, memory, Ethernet or WiFi interfaces, video output, GPIO...? Have you checked Orange Pi, Nano Pi, Banana Pi boards? Most are not quite the same format as the Raspberry Pi Zero but some are quite small.

Comment: The [Orange Pi Lite](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepilite/) could be an option, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @jcaron. These could work as a prototype. I'll update the question to include more details of what I'm looking for for production, which almost certainly will require custom development.

Comment: USB 3.0 ports are probably going to limit options quite a bit. I haven't had needs for USB in my projects so I don't track that in my spreadsheets, but other brands you can check include Odroid, Olimex, Pine64. Also I fear battery-operated and USB 3.0 will not be very good friends. You can ask the companies producing those boards, many of them offer custom design services. You should probably expect a total bill in the 5 figures, though that will depend a lot on what is onboard and the certifications (FCC, CE...) you need. Let us know how that goes for you!

Comment: @jsotola while they may be off-topic on many SE sites, [meta consensus](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/q/174/49) indicates that seeking hardware recommendations **is on topic here**, provided enough detail on requirements is given to make it a specific answerable question.

Comment: @anonymous2 The neat thing about iot.SE is that it's quiet enough that 10 votes gives a consensus :-)

Comment: @jcaron agree that it would be ideal to have a good deal more meta activity... but for the moment it's where things stand and I don't forsee it changing any time in the near future.  The linked post was shortly after we got out of private beta so there were a lot of active users shaping our site scope; while it is possible that sometime in the future we go back to the more standard SE policy, for the moment both meta and precedent indicate that these questions are on-topic.